# Jupyter Notebook Support

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, Lasso, Ridge, LassoCV,
BayesianRidge
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from dmba import regressionSummary, exhaustive_search
from dmba import backward_elimination, forward_selection, stepwise_selection
from dmba import adjusted_r2_score, AIC_score, BIC_score
```

Error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'TypedDict' from 'typing'
(C:\Users\abc\anaconda3\lib\typing.py)
```

Jupyter Notebook version : 6.5.4

Tried

```
pip install dmba
!pip install typing-extensions --upgrade
```

and restarted the kernel.

But still the same error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'TypedDict' from 'typing'
(C:\Users\abc\anaconda3\lib\typing.py)
```

Comment: Where exactly? Please update your post with the full error trace (and remove any code that may come after the error, or may be irrelevant) - see how to create a [mre].